# Is there a way to use two logical operators in a Vue if to check values?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Is there a way to use two logical operators when using a Vue `v-if` that will check if both values are true (That the string is populated?)

```
<div v-if='park.parkCity == "paris" || == "london" '>
```

Comment: The expression in a `v-if` is just JavaScript. So either of `v-if="park.parkCity === 'paris' || park.parkCity === 'london'"` or `v-if="['paris', 'london'].includes(park.parkCity)"` would work.

Comment: Thanks @skirtle However, for some reason both the === as well as == comes back as an error (Invalid Expression and Unexpected token)

Comment: <div v-for =''park in cities" v-if="park.parkCity ==='paris' || park.parkCity ==='london'"> create a object  named cities with two arrays having a property named parkCity.

Comment: @Al-76 Without more context it's difficult to be sure why you're having a problem. Are you defining the template using a string literal? That might explain the error messages you're seeing if you aren't using suitable delimiters for the string.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes for a v-if are illegal.
 `v-if="park.parkCity === 'paris' || park.parkCity === 'london'"` is the correct way.